# Why my upstart script don't work?

Tags: upstart, init

It is strange the script use to work fine,but after the proxy went down for a while,it don't work all the time. But the command in script section can still do it's job,and I have no idea what's going on.

```
description     "Secure Gate Through"


# no start option as you might not want it to auto-start
# This might not be supported - you might need a: start on runlevel [3]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

# if you want it to automatically restart if it crashes, leave the next line in
respawn

script
        plink -v -N proxy@12.34.96.48 -D 127.0.0.1:8580 -pw ****
end script
```

After start,I can see plink in `ps -A`,but the forwarding don't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, why do you not have a '`start on`' condition specified? Do you really only ever want this service to be started manually?

Second, you can simplify the configuration to be just:

```
exec plink -v -N proxy@12.34.96.48 -D 127.0.0.1:8580 -pw ****
```

In other words, you don't need 'script' as that just passes the command through the shell. Next, I'd be very wary of hard-coding a password in a job file like this (and IP addresses etc for that matter).

As to what is causing your job to behave strangely, does `/var/log/upstart/plink.log` give you any indication of the issue?

The Upstart Cookbook provides lots of information you might find useful including:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#checking-how-a-service-might-react-when-run-as-a-job